# Animate the widget app Imageview in which i want to do rotate animation of the image view

Tags: android, animation, android-widget, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I want to develop an widget application in which i want to do some rotate animation of the image view i am confused with with widget provider class i am trying but i am unable to do it if any body don please solve my problem. I am posting my code completely

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider{
    String act;
    private Handler start_handler ;
    private AnimationDrawable analogClockBee_anim = null;
    private ImageView  clock4_bee_Image = null;
    private Animation animation_bee = null;
    RemoteViews myViews;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    act=intent.getAction();
     animation_bee = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f,  Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        animation_bee.setRepeatCount(-1);
        animation_bee.setDuration(35000);
        animation_bee.setInterpolator(context, android.R.anim.linear_interpolator);
       // clock4_bee_Image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.clock_bee_rotate_anim);
        clock4_bee_Image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bee_animation);
        analogClockBee_anim = (AnimationDrawable)clock4_bee_Image.getBackground();
    if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(act)) {
         myViews=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID), myViews);

    }
    myViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.clock_bee_rotate_anim, R.layout.widget);
    start_handler = new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            if(msg.what == 0)
            {
                     analogClockBee_anim.start();           
                     clock4_bee_Image.startAnimation(animation_bee);

            }

        }
    };
    new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {           
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                Log.i("inside handler", "5");
                start_handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                Log.i("inside handler", "6");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
        }
    }).start();
}
}
```

my manifest code

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver android:name=".Widget" android:label="My Custom Clock Widget">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
            </intent-filter>
             <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

rotate animation in anim folder

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
     >

     <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="350"/>
</set>
```

animation drawable folder xml file

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/bee_anim"
     android:oneshot="false"> 

        <item android:drawable="@drawable/bee_0" android:duration="50" />    
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/bee_1" android:duration="50" />    
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/bee_2" android:duration="50" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/bee_3" android:duration="50" />    
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/bee_4" android:duration="50" />    
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/bee_5" android:duration="50" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/bee_6" android:duration="50" />    
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/bee_7" android:duration="50" />    
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/bee_8" android:duration="50" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/bee_9" android:duration="50" />        

</animation-list>
```

manifest referred  xml file app widget provider

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:minWidth="146dp"
             android:minHeight="146dp" 
         android:updatePeriodMillis="0" 
         android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"/>
```

layout widget xml file which contain analog clock widget and image view to be animated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/Widget" 
                android:gravity="center" >

            <AnalogClock
             android:id="@+id/analogClock1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hand_hour="@drawable/clock_4_hour" 
                android:hand_minute="@drawable/clock_4_min"
                android:dial="@drawable/clock_4_bg"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/clock_bee_rotate_anim"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/analogClock1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bee_0" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

please some one solve my problem i have strucked in this problem.thanks in advance

Comment: **You can use this:**
RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(currentDegree,-degree,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
        ra.setDuration(200);
        ra.setFillAfter(true);
        ivCompass.startAnimation(ra);
        currentDegree = -degree;

Comment: its not working i tried

Comment: The degrees have to be continually be changed to give a rotation effect

Comment: i have posted my complete code where i need to use do i need to use it in on Update or where please make it correct and send it to me

Comment: tried with viewflipper. Adding frames as child views in it ?